# Installing "Go For It" application

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install **Go For It**, I have followed the instructions [from here](http://manuel-kehl.de/projects/go-for-it/)

Commands used to install

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:go-for-it-team/go-for-it-daily && sudo apt-get update
```

But I am getting an error Ip address not found   `404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]`

I guess the site is down.

Here's the full output

```
Go For It! is a simple and stylish productivity app, featuring a to-do list, merged with a timer that keeps your focus on the current task.

Website: http://manuel-kehl.de/projects/go-for-it

This ppa provides git versions of Go For It!
For stable versions use https://launchpad.net/~go-for-it-team/+archive/ubuntu/go-for-it-stable
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~go-for-it-team/+archive/ubuntu/go-for-it-daily
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                    
Hit:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                                                                                                         
Hit:4 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                            
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]                                                                                                                                 
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                         
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                         
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/flexiondotorg/minecraft/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                
Hit:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                                                            
Hit:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                                                                         
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/go-for-it-team/go-for-it-daily/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                 
Hit:13 https://repo.fortinet.com/repo/ubuntu /bionic InRelease                                                               
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [18.6 kB]                                      
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease                                      
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                         
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [31.5 kB]                                                    
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                              
Hit:11 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Err:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/go-for-it-team/go-for-it-daily/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/go-for-it-team/go-for-it-daily/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: The PPA author has not created a 20.04-compatible package yet. Feel free to contact them and encourage them. Until then, delete the PPA.

Comment: Thank you, will do it

Comment: Yeah, I did it. No use. I will message the author

Comment: I guess they didn't update there PPA for 20.04. I tried the suggestions but of no use. I asked the author a feature update. Let's see